# Loops python openpyxl. How to add Loops in cells

Tags: python, loops, cell, openpyxl

I'm looking for anyone can help me with make a loop in a load xlsx file on Python.

I need to do some divisions with 2 cells and I can do it to make 1 result but the problem is I need to do this operation with more than 10000 data. I was thinking maybe with a Loop we can do it but I don't know how.

to be more clear, here is two images with the first load xlsx document and the second with my results:

Before

[image: Before]

After

[image: After]

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='Data.xlsx')
ws = wb['Data']

ws.auto_filter.ref = "A1:E1"

ws["E1"] = 'Fillrate%'

ws["E2"] = round(((ws['C2'].value)/(float(ws['B2'].value))*100),2)
ws["E3"] = round(((ws['C3'].value)/(float(ws['B3'].value))*100),2)
ws["E4"] = round(((ws['C4'].value)/(float(ws['B4'].value))*100),2)
ws["E5"] = round(((ws['C5'].value)/(float(ws['B5'].value))*100),2)
ws["E6"] = round(((ws['C6'].value)/(float(ws['B6'].value))*100),2)


wb.save("Analized_Data.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a loop.

First get the number of row, and iterate with `range()` function, like this:

```
max_row = ws.max_row

for index in range(1, max_row + 1):
    ws["E{0}".format(index)] = round((ws['C{0}'.format(index)].value /
                                      float(ws['B{0}'.format(index)].value) * 100), 2)
```

Comment: I can do it with it but I need to start in the row 2 not 1, how can I change the range??

Comment: @MartinBouhier: Replace by `range(2, max_row + 1)`.

Comment: Thanks Laurent. Your info was very helpful!

Comment: If I would like to work with a CVS fill instead of XLSX, how can I write the code??

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to let Excel do the calculation and use a formula. But to answer your question: use `ws.iter_cols(min_col=5, min_row=2, max_col=5)` to get all the cells in column E and loop over it.